# Modern alternative for WCF for Compact Framework

Tags: wcf, web-services, compact-framework, windows-ce

I need to develop a service (better as zero-configured self-contained EXE without [IIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services) needed), clients are smart devices (.NET Compact Framework) looks like this:

[Using WCF in .NET Compact Framework](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37235/Using-WCF-in-NET-Compact-Framework)

Should I still use WCF technology? Is there a modern/lightweight alternative?

Comment: What does "I need to develop Service (better as zero-configured self-contained EXE w/o IIS needed)" mean? Please describe your problem fully.

Comment: Hardware/software requirements for clients: 1..10 WinCE 6.0 devices with Compact Framework 3.5, for Server: Windows XP SP3 or Windows 7 or Windows 2003/2008 Server without installed IIS

Comment: I still do not know what you are trying to achieve. All I know is that you want to have a windows program and a WinCE client. PLEASE edit your post to include much more detail. What is connecting how to where and why?

Comment: Are you trying to Self Host a WCF server? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Hellboy, even if the client devices are old PDAs, that doesn't mean the host must be compatable with WinCE. I have a .NET WCF service (self-hosted on Win Serv 2008) that serves content to WIN CE devices, normal .NET, Java devices and and iOS. There are some compatibility issues when a Win CE devices connects with a regular WCF web service (no SSL, for instance), but most functionality works just fine.

Comment: OK, have you used SOAP or REST? IoC containers?